# How to update new value with old values in ListView in C#

Tags: c#

I need Code for inserting new values to my listview that already have some values. i did my own way but i got Cross Thread Exception. so can anyone help me to insert new values to the listview but don't clear the old values?

thanks in advance,
Ulaga

Comment: show us what you did in your own way. We can make it better

Comment: What have you tried? What does you code look like? You are obviously using `Threads` or a `Backgroundworker`. But there is hardly anything useful to say without seeing some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to show more research effort on your part.  You should also post your non working code, instead of just saying that you got an exception.

Is your application a winform or webform?

System.Windows.Forms.ListView has 6 overloads in its Items collection's Add method, here's three:

```
 listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem("new item"));
 listView1.Items.Add("List item text", 3);  // Adds a new item with ImageIndex 3
 listView1.Items.Add("string");
```

Try them out.

System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView has one way to call its Items collection's Add method:

```
 ListView1.Items.Add(ListViewDataItem item);
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983548(v=vs.71).aspx